# Redirect subdomain to main domain except one url

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I have a main domain as follows

**Main domain : http://www.sample.com/**

**Sub domain : http://dev.sample.com/**

Now If any one access http://dev.sample.com/ It needs to redirect to  http://www.sample.com/
So I added the following code in my sub domain It works very well

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.sample.com.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sample.com.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But from subdomain if any access the following url **http://dev.sample.com/data** then 
it should not redirect to main domain. It should stay on that sub domain page. Any one have idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?data
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/data [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, this will prevent all URL's with /data at the start of the URI.  So if you had http://blog.sample.com/data it would also allow it to resolve without the rewrite.  If this is a problem you can get more complex... after this rule add this to catch all non-dev subdomains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !dev\.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now if the first condition set is not met the first rule won't run, so check to make sure you're only serving dev and www up with /data.

Comment: Nice one ! ! ! Worked Like A Charm :)